# Flutter Don't allow leading whitespaces in TextField

Tags: regex, flutter, dart, whitespace, textfield

I have a simple `TextField` where the user should not be allowed to type in **leading whitespaces**. I found a couple of similar answers about removing whitespaces from `Strings` or don't allow any whitespaces. But in my case the only restriction should be  leading whitespaces.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59064789/is-there-a-way-to-automatically-remove-or-avoid-leading-and-trailing-spaces-in-a) is what I found for `TextFields` but that is removing all whitespaces.

Can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create your own `TextInputFormatter` and change returned value of `formatEditUpdate(...)`.

Sample:

```
class NoLeadingSpaceFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(
    TextEditingValue oldValue,
    TextEditingValue newValue,
  ) {
    if (newValue.text.startsWith(' ')) {
      final String trimedText = newValue.text.trimLeft();

      return TextEditingValue(
        text: trimedText,
        selection: TextSelection(
          baseOffset: trimedText.length,
          extentOffset: trimedText.length,
        ),
      );
    }

    return newValue;
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
TextField(
  inputFormatters: [
    NoLeadingSpaceFormatter(),
  ],
),
```

Answer (score 1):

No leading whitespace regex is

```
^\S
^(?!\s)
```

In Dart, do not forget to use raw string literals, `r"^\S"` or `r"^(?!\s)"`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ehccDv/1).

**Details**

- `^\S` - any non-whitespace char (`\S`) at the start of string
- `^(?!\s)` - a start of string (`^`) position that cannot be immediately followed with a whitespace (`(?!\s)` is a negative lookahead).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`trimRight()`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.4/dart-core/String/trimRight.html) method:

> The string without any trailing whitespace.
>
> As [`trim`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.4/dart-core/String/trim.html), but only removes trailing whitespace.

```
void main() {
 print('\t Space\t. Dart is fun\t\t'.trimRight()); // '  Space  . Dart is fun'
}
```