# How to restrict first character by text only in text form field in flutter?

Tags: flutter

Text input should not be space as initial. once user write some charater it allows to put space between two words. but as an initial character it supports only and only text in text form field.

Comment: do you mean that you don't want to calculate space as a character especially when the user types it first?

Comment: Yes. I want to block space as an initial character

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67394385/8597548

Please refer this link, it is provided by @rickimaru

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to restrict space as an initial character, you can achieve that by `inputFormatters`, here's an example:

```
class NoInitialSpaceInputFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
    // Prevent entering a space as the initial character
    if (newValue.text.startsWith(' ')) {
      return oldValue;
    }
    return newValue;
  }
}
```

And pass it as a `inputFormatters` to `TextField` like this:

```
TextField(
    inputFormatters: [NoInitialSpaceInputFormatter()],
)
```