# How can I convert text with spaces to single space in TextFormField?

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I convert text with too many spaces to single space? For example name: **"Brad Pit"** there is only one space between first and last name but user can write **"Brad  (4 space)  Pit"** with too much space. How can I reduce this to single space in TextFormField?

Answer (score 2):

Code:

```
void main() {
  var name = 'Pratik      Butani';
  print(name);
  print(name.replaceAll(new RegExp(r"\s+"), " "));
}
```

Output:

```
Pratik      Butani
Pratik Butani
```

Explanation: Here I have used RegExp which will take continue spaces using **\s+** and It will be replaced by one space.

You can this demo on [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/dart?null_safety=true)

Do let me know if you have any confusion.

Answer (score 1):

In Dart u can use:

```
print(yourString.trim())
```

to convert text with too many spaces

and u can try this

```
String name = 'Brad    Pit ';
print(name.replaceAll(new RegExp(r"\s+"), ""));
```

Answer (score 0):

To reduce multiple space to a single space
Please refer to this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1981366/9414608

Also you can prevent users from adding spaces in the TextFormField by using inputFormatters

Please refer to this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59065304/9414608

[flutter](/questions/tagged/flutter)[dart](/questions/tagged/dart)[whitespaces](/questions/tagged/whitespaces)[textformfield](/questions/tagged/textformfield)[string](/questions/tagged/string)